# "Is There A/Any Book On The Table?"?

Tags: difference

Are these types of questions equally idiomatic and common:

Is there a book on the table?
Is there any book on the table?

How do they differ in meaning and usage?

Answer (score 0):

"Is there a book on the table?" is something you say if you think there is either no books or just one book on the table. It implies there aren't usually lots of books on the table: maybe you call a restaurant because you think you might have left the book you were reading.

"Are there any books on the table?" is more general, and can be used when you suspect there are no, one, or more than one books on the table. If there are often many books on the table, such as in a library, it would be more usual to ask this.

You use "is there any" with a mass (uncountable) noun, such as "Is there any food on the table?"

Saying "is there any" with a countable noun is less common. You might say "Is there any reason I should do that?" Typically it suggests you think the answer is "no", there is none. "Is there any book you think I should read?" is more doubtful, less expecting an answer, than "Are there any books you think I should read?"

See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34353/is-there-versus-are-there) on English Language Usage SE.